# I'm getting Not a Number value in my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Can't render the noofcartItems in my react UI. I get only NaN value as output in my UI.
Anything wrong in the syntax ? The context I created also seems to be failing.
Please ignore the console logs as I used it for debug purposes.

```
import CartContext from '../../CartStore/cart-context.js';
import CartIcon from '../Cart/CartIcon.js';
import './CartButton.css';
import { useContext } from 'react';

const CartButton = (props) => {


    const context = useContext(CartContext);

    const noofcartItems = context.items.reduce((curNo, item) => {
        console.log(curNo, item.amount,curNo + item.amount, 'curNo + item.amount');
        return curNo + item.amount;
    }, 0);
    console.log(noofcartItems,'No of cart items');
    return (<button  className='button' onClick={props.onClick}>

        <span className='icon'>
             <CartIcon/>
        </span>
        <span>Cart</span>
        <span className='badge'>{noofcartItems}</span>
    </button>
    )
};

export default CartButton;

import React from 'react'

const CartContext = React.createContext({
    items:[],
    totalAmount: 0,
    addItem: (item) => {},
    removeItem: (id) => {}
});

export default CartContext;
```

Comment: What is the value of `item.amount`?

Comment: @vlaz item.amount is my input value. It will add to curNo which is 0 by default.

Comment: @mani but what values do you get there? You've logged them. At some point, at least one of them is probably `undefined` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should console log your `context.items` array and check for the values of `amount` variable. It seems that one of the amount values must be `undefined`.